# How to transfer string selected from listview of one fragment to autocompleteTextview of another fragment over the same activity

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a listview on one fragment which consists of all the buses coming to a particular bus stop as listitems. I want when user click on any route no. listed in the listview, to get transferred to the autocomplete textview on another fragment on the same activity with the same value copied to autocompletetextview which he selected from the list in first fragment. On 2nd fragment user can see the detailed journey of that particular bus no. which he selected before

Comment: if you have a list of buses what do you need `AutoCompleteTextView` for? use either `ListView` or `ACTV`

Answer (score 1):

```
            write this in firstFragment listView itemclick;
            @Override
                public void onItemClick(Items item) {
                    String busnumber =  item.getBusNumber();
                    SecondFragment sFragment = new SecondFragment();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("bNumber", busnumber);
                    sFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.activity_container_id, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
                    ft.commit();

                }

            than on second fragment in onCreate method get the bus number or string value you passed as bundle argument from first fragment and set it to autocomplete text.
        so second fragment something look like this: 

   onCreate(){
            Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
            String bNumber;
            if (bundle != null) {
                bNumber = bundle.getString("bNumber", "");
            }

          AutoCompleteTextView actv= 
         (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1); 
         actv.setText(bNumber);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most efficiently you can do is, create an **Interface** with function like **onRouteSelected()** then implement that Interface in FragmentOne and pass the FragmentOne reference to you adapter. whenever the user clicks on any rout, call the onRouteSelected() of your interface from adapter. This way you will get the RoutNo Clicked callback in Fragment one .Now you can send that data to FragmentTwo and use it as per your need.

Comment: why are you putting your answer in a comment block?

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to create interface in first fragment and implement it in MainActivity and in override method of interface call public method of second fragment and update UI in that method

FirstFragment extends Fragment {   

public    onClick mOnClick;
    public interface  onClick
    {
        public void onItenClick(String click);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mOnClick = (onClick ) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement MyInterface ");
        }
    }

}


public class TabActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FirstTabFragment.onClick {
 @Override
    public void onItenClick(String click) {

        SecondTabFragment page = (SecondTabFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.vpPager + ":1");
        page.getData(click);
    }
}

and in SecondTabFragment write down your public method
 public void getData(String click)
    {
       //update your UI here
    }
```